# Push and pop a full 128-bit NEON register to/from the stack in AArch64

Tags: assembly, stack, arm, arm64

I have found in AArch64 the documentation how to push/pop pairs of 64-bit registers with `STP`/`LDP`. I understand they can take lower 64 bits of 128-bit NEON floating-point registers as parameters, such as:

```
@ Push D0, D1
STP D0, D1, [SP, #-16]!
@ Pop D0, D1
LDP D0, D1, [SP], #16
```

However, how to push/pop the full 128 bit of a NEON floating-point register in AArch64? Will the following work? (My doubt is that it will not decrement/increment the `SP` register)

```
STR Q0, [SP, #-16]!
LDR Q0, [SP], #16
```

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't update `SP`. Anyway, when in doubt, use a debugger :)

Comment: What happened when you tried to assemble/run it? What does your instruction set reference have to say on the matter?

Comment: @Ross Ridge - how about stp q0, q1, [sp, #-(16*2)]! ?

Comment: @Notlikethat, I haven't yet done that because the infrastructure is not yet setup. Just coding/designing for now.

Comment: You realise the ABI only requires that you store the first 64 bits, right?  Are you saving the registers to comply with the calling convention, or because you need to preserve them for your own purposes?

Comment: @sh1, initially I wanted to push the whole 128-bit register in order to keep the 128-bit stack alignment required in AArch64. Can you give a link in support of that claim about ABI? As far as I know (now), `clang -O3` can generate functions taking 128-bit parameters in dedicated vector registers and returning 128-bit value in a single register. Try `float32x4_t` type from `arm_neon.h`.

Comment: [aacps64](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0055b/IHI0055B_aapcs64.pdf) page 15, section 5.1.2.  It's just a role for what needs saving.  Arguments are still free to use the whole register.  You keep 128-bit alignment just by pushing two 64-bit registers as a pair, so you needn't worry about that.  I'd say it's easier, overall, to get the toolchain first and then use that to check your assumptions, and to see what the preferred idioms are, as you go.

Comment: @sh1, due to the specifics of what I'm doing (compiler tooling), I need to save full 128 bits of the registers of interest. However, your reference is useful because it seems to tell me to save `v8-v15` too, because their higher 64 bits can be overwritten by the called functions.

Answer (score 2):

The brief description of memory access is here ([Floating-point and NEON scalar loads and stores](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.den0024a/ch06s03s03.html))

```
STR Q0, [sp, #-16]!      // Save 128b (16B)
STP Q0, Q1, [sp, #-32]!  // Save 2x128b (2 x 16B = 32B)
```

Also `Qx` registers could be accessed as NEON/FTP `Vx` registers.
([NEON and Floating-Point architecture](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.den0024a/BABIGHEB.html))
([Vector register sizes](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.den0024a/ch04s06s03.html))

```
st1 {v0.2d}, [sp]  // Save Q0 (V0 is 'vector' alias)
```

More practical usage is to preserve all "Callee-saved registers" (v8-v15)

```
sub sp, sp, #func_stack_size
st1 { v8.2d,  v9.2d, v10.2d, v11.2d}, [sp], #64
st1 {v12.2d, v13.2d, v14.2d, v15.2d}, [sp], #64
```